# NSTimer does't work when device lock

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a app that i want work in background for every time and only when the user closed(terminated) it fails(like daily alarm). My code is:

AppDelegate:

```
 - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
    {
        backgroundUpdateTask = 0;
        return YES;
    }

    - (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application{
    }

    - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application{

backgroundUpdateTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        [self endBackgroundUpdateTask];
    }];
        if (application.applicationIconBadgeNumber > 0) {
            application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
        }
    }

    - (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application{
        [self endBackgroundUpdateTask];

        if (application.applicationIconBadgeNumber > 0) {
            application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
        }
    }

    - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application{
        lte = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"LTE"];
        if (lte == nil) {
            [Utility GetNewNotification:lte];
            lte = [[[notifyDic objectForKey: @"Notification"]valueForKey:@"LTE"]valueForKey:@"text"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:lte forKey:@"LTE"];
        }
    }

    - (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application{
    }

    - (void)endBackgroundUpdateTask{
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication]endBackgroundTask:backgroundUpdateTask];
        backgroundUpdateTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }
```

and View Controler:

```
@implementation ViewController
{
    NSTimer *myTimer;
    int counter;
}

-(void)CheckTimer{
    if(counter == 0){
        counter = 60;
        NSString* lte = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"LTE"];
        [Utility GetNewNotification:lte];
    }
    else {
        counter --;
        //do your video playing work here
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];
    /// Counter for get new notification
    counter = 60;
    myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(CheckTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

I want every 60 second timer is trigger and service is call. but after 180 second after app go to background timer is down. and if device is lock timer is down too.

Comment: Since iOS 7.1 you can run that 3 minutes in background or if you want than at max you can run it 10 minutes using `[[UIApplicationsharedApplication]
          beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
             
          }]`

Comment: you might want to learn more about how the background execution works on iOS __[from the best](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)__ _(spoiler-alert: Apple)_.

Comment: I read every document and i know all that. but want app more than 3 minutes or 10 minutes(like alarm clock)

Comment: Almost sounds like you want a notification of some kind?

Comment: when you set alarm in other alarm clock app like "Sleep Cycle alarm clock" if device is lock that alarm in time.That's right?

Comment: As already wrote by holex, is better that you read apple doc about how background execution works and background modes. If your app doesn't fit in a specific list of categories you can't. Pay attention that the category you eventually choose will be part of review by the Apple review team. So if your app doesn't need location but you flag it for background locations, it will be probably rejected.

Comment: Some battery killer app. Isn't would better to use push notifications?

Comment: i know battery killer. and know best solution is use push notification. but my employer want solve this problem without use push notification :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**To run code in background refer this link :-**
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

**Notes :-**

1. Apps only get 10 mins of background execution - after this time duration the        timer will stop firing.
2. As of iOS 7 or higher when the device is locked it
   will suspend the foreground app almost instantly. The timer will not fire after an iOS 7 or higher app is locked.

Answer (score 0):

@Darshan Mothreja is correct with his answer. If you want to run code in the Background you have a limited time to actually do things. After that time is expired you are out of luck until your application comes back to the foreground.

Depending on what you are trying to accomplish you might want to look at the lifecycle methods in your AppDelegate.

Youre probably going to want to look at the method:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application;
```

and add some more update code to it. This will allow you to update things or fetch new data as the application is returning to the foreground.